# PermGen Exception during mvn clean install, but not during install

Tags: java, maven, permgen

I have what seems to be simple questions yet it is confusing me.

How much impact on a PermGen memory can phase clean have?

I have a situation where I am configuring a maven build on TFS 2015. I have no control over build machine so I often have problem with PermGen Exception and I had to divide the this build into many smaller steps.

So I have a profile that builds fine after calling mvn install, but during mvn clean install it throws PermGen Exception.

I am a little bit confused here as I have never thought that phase clean would have impact on any JVM memory, as it just removes all the files that were generated during previous builds of those artifacts.

I will be glad for any deeper insight into mvn clean and how JVM and Maven handles cases of clean install and install separately.

Comment: First PermGen Space is something in a JVM till JDK 7 in JDK 8 it has been removed. Furthermore how have you configured the JVM (memeory parameter)? From where is the Maven build started?

Comment: I have to use JDK 7 as it is a long going project and upgrade to 8 is not yet scheduled. Maven build is started at TFS build agent as I have written. I have no control over the machine so I cannot set MAVEN_OPTS and I cannot pass a JVM command line parameter as TFS allows only for maven options ( entering -XX:MaxPermSize gives Exception from maven. Something about unrecognized plugin prefix "X" )

Comment: You have to set that either on JAVA_OPTS or on MAVEN_OPTS if you are able to set MAVEN_OPTS and are not able to set JAVA_OPTS you are simply lost.

Comment: I am not asking for solution to PermGen problem. I know that one already. I am simply asking for some insight why clean install needs more memory than just install. Clean should just do the cleanup of files from previous builds so why it causes PermGen to happen. I expect that a little as it is an additional phase, so obviously it will take some more memory to run, but not so much to cause PermGen to happen.

Comment: Is the Maven process running alone within a single JVM instance or is there something else running within the same JVM ? Based on TFS ? Furthermore how have you set memory settings etc. ?

Comment: The Maven process is running in a single JVM instance. No other process is run on this build agent at that time. And memory settings are set by MAVEN_OPTS="XX:MaxPermSize=512".

Comment: But that is not the problem here. I want ot know how clean handles memory.   Because it seems that clean do not clean after itself. If clean install causes PermGen exception and install alone do not, then my conclusion is that clean and install are in some chain and there are things left in JVM memory after clean finishes. But why? That is what interest me. Is it a JVM problem/feature? Or maybe clean leaves something in memory and GC does not clean it automatically? Or phases after clean needs some stuff from it?